# Stream Filter from another Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm attempting to filter a Map using a stream. The predicate/condition I'm filtering by is another stream. I'm currently encountering the issue of IllegalStateException, probably because I'm accessing a stream which has already been accessed.

```
Map<Integer, Double> table = Map.of(10, 8.0,
                                    15, 10.0,
                                    20, 28.0,
                                    40, 40.0);

Stream<Double> streamDbl = getDoublefromInt(table, Stream.of(20, 40));
```

Referencing [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-find-list-items) website, I came up with something like the code segment below but it does not work.

```
public static Stream<Double> getDoublefromInt(Map<Integer, Double> table, Stream<Integer> id) {
 return table.entrySet().stream
        .filter(map -> id.anyMatch(id -> id.equals(map.getKey())))
        .map(map -> map.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to filter a Map using a stream? How about collecting the stream into a set/list first?

Comment: You'll consume the second stream every time you call `#anyMatch` on the it. You very much likely want a `Set` for a quick/hashed `O(1)` `#contains` check, not a `Stream` that would require an `O(n)` traversal

Comment: Stream isn't the tool for the job in the filter, IMO. Use a `Set`. It contains the method... `contains`, which does by itself what you do in the lambda within the lambda in your `filter` operation.

Comment: If I understood the task correctly, then your solution is simply `return id.map(table::get);` in your `getDoublefromInt()`

Answer (score 1):

Stream is a basically an iterator over the source of data, it's **not** a container of data (like Collections). Once it's consumed, it can't be used anymore. For that reason, you're getting an `IllegalStateException` by trying to fire the same stream multiple times.

You don't need Stream IPA for what you're trying to achieve, functionality offered by the Collections framework would be sufficient for that.

All the heavy lifting can be done using [`Collection.retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
public static Stream<Double> getDoubleFromInt(Map<Integer, Double> table, Stream<Integer> id) {
    
    Set<Integer> idSet = id.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Map<Integer, Double> copy = new HashMap<>(table);
    
    copy.keySet().retainAll(idSet);
    
    return copy.values().stream();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stream `Supplier`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Double> table = Map.of(
        10, 8.0,
        15, 10.0,
        20, 28.0,
        40, 40.0);

    Stream<Double> streamDbl = getDoublefromInt(table, () -> Stream.of(20, 40));

    streamDbl.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static Stream<Double> getDoublefromInt(Map<Integer, Double> table, Supplier<Stream<Integer>> ids) {
    return table.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(map -> ids.get().anyMatch(id -> id.equals(map.getKey())))
        .map(map -> map.getValue());
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
28.0
40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**BE SIMPLE!!!**

Why do not you use incomming `Stream`?

```java
public static Stream<Double> getDoubleFromInt(Map<Integer, Double> table,
                                              Stream<Integer> id) {
    return id.map(table::get)
             .filter(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Looks like the result `Stream` will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what it means to filter the map? If you want to get stream of values from the map that corresponds to the keys that are specified in the other stream, then the solution is simple:

```
public class Main {
    static Map<Integer, Double> table = Map.of(10, 8.0,
            15, 10.0,
            20, 28.0,
            40, 40.0);

    public static Stream<Double> getDoubleFromInt(Map<Integer, Double> table, Stream<Integer> id) {
        return id.map(table::get);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getDoubleFromInt(table, Stream.of(20, 40))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

prints

```
28.0
40.0
```

Perhaps you need to decide what to do if there is no value for the some keys, in this case there will be Null in the stream. Or you may filter out this Null values.